# fwrite with structs containing an array

Tags: c++, struct, fwrite, fread

How do I fwrite a struct containing an array

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

typedef struct {
  int ref; 
  double* ary;
} refAry;

void fillit(double *a,int len){
  for (int i=0;i<len;i++) a[i]=i;
}

int main(){
  refAry a;
  a.ref =10;
  a.ary = new double[10];
  fillit(a.ary,10);
  FILE *of;
  if(NULL==(of=fopen("test.bin","w")))
     perror("Error opening file");
  fwrite(&a,sizeof(refAry),1,of);

  fclose(of);
  return 0;
}
```

The filesize of test.bin is 16 bytes, which I guess is (4+8) (int + double*). The filesize should be 4+10*8 (im on 64bit)

```
~$ cat test.bin |wc -c
16
~$ od -I test.bin 
0000000                   10             29425680
0000020
~$ od -fD test.bin -j4
0000004   0,000000e+00   7,089709e-38   0,000000e+00
                     0       29425680              0
0000020
```

thanks

Comment: You seem to be writing pure C but then what's with the inclusion of <iostream>?

Comment: `new` isn't in C where I come from...

Comment: And `new` without a matching `delete`?

Comment: Well that's still C++.  Bad C++, but C++ nonetheless.

Comment: Actually the file size should be (8 + 10 * 8) not (4 + 10 * 8), assuming you correct the code to write the array as represented in memory.  Since you're on a 64 bit platform the size of a pointer is 64 bits.  Your struct members will be aligned on an 8 byte boundary because the size your pointer is larger than the size of your int.  This means that there will be 4 bytes of padding between your int member and the pointer, which is why the size of your struct is 16, not 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing the pointer (a memory address) into the file, which is not what you want. You want to write the content of the block of memory referenced by the pointer (the array). This can't be done with a single call to fwrite. I suggest you define a new function:

```
void write_my_struct(FILE * pf, refAry * x)
{
    fwrite(&x->ref, sizeof(x->ref), 1, pf);
    fwrite(x->ary, sizeof(x->ary[0]), x->ref, pf);
}
```

You'll need a similar substitute for fread.

Answer (score 1):

Your structure doesn't actually contain an array, it contains a pointer.  If you really want variable-length structures, you'll need to keep a size field in there so that you know how big it is.  The [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/struct/structhack.html) has an example of exactly what it looks you're trying to do.  In your case it might look something like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int ref; 
    double ary[1];
} refAry;

#define SIZE_OF_REFARY (sizeof(refAry) - sizeof(double))
```

To allocate:

```
size_t alloc_size = SIZE_OF_REFARY + 10*sizeof(double);
refAry *a = malloc(alloc_size);
a->ref = 10;
```

To write:

```
fwrite(a, SIZEP_OF-REFARY + a->ref * sizeof(double), 1, file);
```

Comment: Check his code, `ref` acts as the size field. BTW, this code is a total hack, I don't think it should be recommended.

Comment: Oh yeah, ok.  I'll go clean that up.  I'll go along with not recommended, but it's definitely popular; there's a *lot* of code out there that behaves this way.

Answer (score 0):

Your structure contains a pointer, not an array of 10.  the sizeof() picks that up.

You'll need something like fwrite(a.ary, sizeof(double), 10, of); in order to write the actual array

Answer (score 0):

If the size of the array is always 10, then simply change your struct to:

```
typedef struct {
  int ref; 
  double ary[10];
} refAry;
```

You can then write this out with a single call to fwrite, using sizeof(refAry) for the size.

Comment: I guess he wants to have a dynamic array, otherwise he doesn't need to store the size (`ref`).